# What is the age minimum to play in the National Basketball Association, (NBA)?

Tags: basketball

I was wondering if you needed to be of a certain age to play professional basketball. Do you need a college degree? Or can you play straight from high school?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be at least 19 years old during the calendar year when the draft is held.

-No, you do not need a college degree.

This is supposed to stop any prospect from going straight to the BNBA directly out of high school.
(The idea behind that was to force high school graduates to go to college for at least one year) But, they do not need to go to college in that year. They can decide to play overseas.

Comment: Forcing high school graduates to do _something_ for a year anyway - it is no longer absolutely necessary to go to college as players can join the G League or play professionally overseas (Australia being the most common).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Correct, thank you! I meant - that was the idea of why they made them wait a year. But yes, playing overseas is what some decide to do instead.